# Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I'm writing a report with several imported code (I'm using `listing` package), and I come across the error in the title when the compiler started parsing one of the imported code text.
Looking at the log file I've found these lines:

```
The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.
Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as the first line of the file
or specify an encoding such as \usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
in the document preamble.
Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool
```

Following these instructions I've added `\UseRawInputEncoding` at the beginning of my latex file. Then I've checked the encoding type of the file imported as the others is UTF-8 but nothing worked.
Any suggestion would be appreciated:)

My latex preamble:

```
\UseRawInputEncoding
%PREAMBOLO
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\definecolor{codegreen}{RGB}{42, 184, 42}
\definecolor{codeblue}{RGB}{48, 48, 255}
\definecolor{codered}{RGB}{223, 15, 15}
\definecolor{codeyellownum}{RGB}{183, 183, 38}
\definecolor{codeyellowstring}{RGB}{251, 191, 71}
\definecolor{backcolour}{RGB}{236, 239, 244}

\lstdefinestyle{global}{
    language=Octave,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    backgroundcolor={\color{backcolour}},
    commentstyle={\color{codegreen}},
    keywordstyle={\color{codeblue}},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\color{codered}},
    otherkeywords={;,+,-,*,/,.,=,++,(,),[,],=+,=-},
    morekeywords=[2]{;,+,-,*,/,.,=,++,(,),[,],=+,=-},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{codeyellowstring},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    literate={à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1,
}

\lstset{style=global}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=25mm,
right=15mm,
top=25mm,
bottom=25mm
}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

% Cambiare impostazioni di pagina
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Lunghezza indentazione

% Dichiarazione nuovi comandi
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\restr}[2]{\left.#1\right|_{#2}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
% ALGEBRA
\newcommand{\acts}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-170}{$\circlearrowright$}}
%
%

% Dichiarazioni nuovi ambienti
\newtheorem*{deff}{\normalfont\scshape Definizione}
\newtheorem*{thm}{\normalfont\scshape Teorema}
\newtheorem*{prop}{\normalfont\scshape Proposizione}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{\normalfont\scshape Lemma}
\newtheorem*{cor}{\normalfont\scshape Corollario}
\newtheorem*{oss}{\normalfont\scshape Osservazione}
\newtheorem*{example}{\normalfont\scshape Esempio}
\newtheorem*{exe}{\normalfont\scshape Esercizio}
```

Comment: if you get that error the document is presumably not in UTF-8, if you can not re-save it as UTF-8 then remove `UseRawInputEncoding` and replace `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` by the encoding the file uses, possibly `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

Comment: I've figured out that the error was generated by the letter "È" and removed that makes the error disappears. However I coudn't (wanted) remove that letter so I've change latex engine to xelatex and all worked perfectly.

Comment: The fix you describe does not match the problem description. You must have re-saved the file as utf-8 otherwise it would not work with xelatex, and if it is in utf-8 you would not have the invalid utf-8 sequence i=error from pdflatex either,

Comment: overleaf saves bbl files as non-utf and causes this error (e.g `output.bbl: LaTeX document, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text`) strangely it doesn't seem to cause an issue with the compilation to pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I updated my OS to Monterey I had the same issue.  (I really updated my MacBook about 7 generations... which included the new OS)  **I found that the issue was I had a number of '–' vs '-' in my files - and similar non standard characters.**  (Long dash vs just a dash... I am moving a draft book from MS Word to LaTex. Word adds the long dashes automatically.)  When I eliminated them this solved the problem.